# Background image not rendering with ReactJS (using URL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render a card with a background image, however, the image is not showing up with this current syntax. I've tried substituting ${this.props.flat.imageUrl} for src and that doesn't work. The price and flat name are rendering though. Not sure where to go from here.

```
  render() {
const src = this.props.flat.imageUrl;
return (
  <div
    className="card" style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(('${this.props.flat.imageUrl}')`
    }}
  >
    <p className="card-category">{this.props.flat.price}</p>
    <p className="card-description">{this.props.flat.name}</p>
  </div>
);
```

}

Comment: you have unbalanced parentheses around your css rule.  what happens if you fix them?

Comment: Just what I was about to type @DanO

Comment: Did that! but still hasn't fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have an extra `(` in your `backgroundImage` property. I would also suggest moving your style out of the return for better readability like so:

```
export default function App() {
    const src = 'https://png.pngtree.com/element_our/png/20180928/beautiful-hologram-water-color-frame-png_119551.jpg';
    const style = {backgroundImage: `url(${src})`}
    return (
      <div
        className="card" style={style}
      >
        <p className="card-category">$23</p>
        <p className="card-description">Some name here</p>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: I just tried using this syntax and it's still not working :( I also double checked that the URL's are correct and there's no problem with them

Comment: @csch99 Here is a sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-wilson-xrwge?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I took a look at the sandbox and I used the same syntax but it wasn't working. I copy and pasted my code into the sandbox if you'd like to take a look. The images are still not displaying..

Answer (score 0):

Inline-Style is not properly applied to the `backgroundImage`. Try this;

```
   backgroundImage: `url(${this.props.flat.imageUrl})`
```

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces inside backgroundImage property are wrong. Please try below code.

```
  render() {
    const src = this.props.flat.imageUrl;
    return (
        <div
            className="card" style={{
                backgroundImage: "url(" + src + ")"
            }}
        >
            <p className="card-category">{this.props.flat.price}</p>
            <p className="card-description">{this.props.flat.name}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to be working for me.. with that syntax the style isn't even showing up when I inspect the page

Comment: Please try like this > style ={ { backgroundImage: "url('https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/MOf9Kxxkj7GvyZlTZOnUzuYv0JAweEhlxJX6gslQvbvlhLK5_bSTK6duxY2xfbBsj43H=w300')" } }